# How shareable is /var/cache?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, directory-structure, cache, shared-disk

I know that some subdirectories of `/var/cache` are pretty much shareable, for example `/var/cache/pacman` (in case of ArchLinux), and possibly others (`/var/cache/man`?), but at least `/var/cache/ldconfig` seems to me pretty much local.

Is it possible to make such a setup that I have a partition for local cache and another one for cache that is shared between different hosts? What should be taken into consideration?

On this specific case it is ok to assume that same base distribution of Linux (ArchLinux) is used, but architectures may differ (even arm, even though it is not the same ArchLinux distribution than x86 and x86_64 in some sense).